# how to build Qt5 project with cuda?

Tags: qt, cuda, qt5

I have a project written with Qt (Win32, VS2010) and CUDA, and my cu file includes Qt headers. When I tried to build my project with new Qt 5.0 (it is Ok with Qt 4.8.3), I had the following errors:

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/msvc2010/include\QtCore/qobject_impl.h(82): error: too many initializer values

C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/msvc2010/include\QtCore/qobject_impl.h(85): error: too many initializer values

C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/msvc2010/include\QtCore/qobject_impl.h(89): error: too many initializer values
```

I created a simple project to reproduce the bug and it was reproduced. I believe it can be repeated with any Qt project with CUDA that uses Qt headers. However, I added simple code to reproduce the error below. Can anyone help me?

test1.pro file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = qt_cuda_test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


OTHER_FILES += \
    kernel.cu

INCLUDEPATH += $$quote($$(CUDA_INC_PATH))
CUDA_SOURCES    +=  kernel.cu

CUDA_SDK = "C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 5.0/C"   # Path to cuda SDK install
CUDA_DIR = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v5.0"            # Path to cuda toolkit install
SYSTEM_NAME = Win32         # Depending on your system either 'Win32', 'x64', or 'Win64'
SYSTEM_TYPE = 32            # '32' or '64', depending on your system
CUDA_ARCH = sm_20           # Type of CUDA architecture, for example 'compute_10', 'compute_11', 'sm_10'
NVCC_OPTIONS = --use_fast_math

# include paths
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include \
               $$CUDA_SDK/common/inc/ \
               $$CUDA_SDK/../shared/inc/ \

# library directories
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME \
                $$CUDA_SDK/common/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME \
                $$CUDA_SDK/../shared/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME
# Add the necessary libraries
LIBS += -lcuda -lcudart

# The following library conflicts with something in Cuda
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib

# The following makes sure all path names (which often include spaces) are put between quotation marks
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')

# Configuration of the Cuda compiler
cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC -I"C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/msvc2010/include" $$LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
```

kernel.cu file:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, size_t size);

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 5;
    const int a[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);
    return 0;
}

// do something with cuda
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, size_t size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_b = 0;
    int *dev_c = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
}
```

Comment: The usual solution is not to import complex host C++ template headers into code which will be compiled through nvcc. Trying moving your `addWithCuda` wrapper into a separate .cu file and link it the main host code, rather than have both in the same compilation unit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I understand there are no other ways to solve the problem